# jquery conditional selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="test mypro demo-class" id="test-1">test</div>
<div class="test mypro demo-class" id="test-3">test</div>
<div class="test mypro demo-class" id="test-4">test 2 no demo class</div>
<div class="test mypro" id="test-2">test 2 no demo class</div>
```

in the above code i want to remove the div with id#test-2 with an additional condition check of div should not have .demo-class
i tried this

```
$("#test-2 div:not(.demo-class)").remove();
```

please help 
thanks in advance

Comment: You can't have two same ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#test-2").not('.demo-class').remove();
```

but I reccomend you to use unique ID use classes instead!

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: yes i use unique id in my code ,here i gave for some example code

Comment: if ID is unique is no-sense to check if has a class or not because exist only this element with that id @KarthickKumarGanesh

Comment: i my application i dynamically replace id based on the class

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you've two elements with `id` **test-2**, chane it to class:

```
<div class="test mypro demo-class test-2">test 2 no demo class</div>
<div class="test mypro test-2">test 2 no demo class</div>
```

and then use:

```
$(".test-2:not(.demo-class)").remove()
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T53nS/)